# Do we call these "holes" or "gaps"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

[image]

[image]

My children have a board like the picture 1 above and there are some flat wooden pieces in the shape of animals like the picture 2 above.

There are some holes in the board and the children will put the correct pieces into the holes.

Do we call these holes "**holes**" or "**gaps**"?

or
can we just say "**the children can do the picture jigsaw**"?

Comment: Can't fool me. That whale doesn't fit any of those holes. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Those are holes or spaces.

A "gap" is a *complete separation* in something continuous, like a number line with a number missing, or a wall with a space to walk through. But the holes in your picture don't separate the yellow surface as it's still connected around the hole.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably call them "empty spaces", but "holes" is OK, too. A "gap" is usually in one dimension (e.g., a gap in a row of people or in a timeline), but it would certainly be understandable in this context, too.

Yes, we can also use the verb "do" (although ["jigsaw puzzle"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jigsaw_puzzle) usually refers to a different kind of puzzle):

> The children do the puzzle.

However, "do" is very vague, so a verb like "work on" or "complete" would probably sound better in most contexts.